# Elasticsearch query that counts points in geo_shapes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed a lot of geo_shapes that are the borders of various countries. The mapping is like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "country": {
      "properties": {
        "border": {
          "type": "geo_shape"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also have a lot of points indexed that are mapped like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "point": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_shape"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An example for a point would be like this:

```
{
  "location": {
    "type": "point",
    "coordinates": [30.706049, 6.264897]
  },
  "a": "a"
}
```

The `"a"` is just for counting because I wasn't able to use value_count aggregations to count `"location"`.

I know that I can count the points in a country like this:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "location": {
        "relation": "within",
        "indexed_shape": {
          "index": "geo",
          "type": "country",
          "id": "Austria",
          "path": "border"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Austria": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "a"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make a query that takes all the points, matches them with the country and then counts the points per country or do I have do make separate requests for every country?